# Как протестировать приватный Injected обьект?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, testng

Как протестировать приватный Injected обьект?

Есть код:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    private SecondClass secondClass;

    public boolean isInProgres() {
        if (secondClass.isTaskInProgress()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

В тестах я хочу сделать что-то типа:

```
when(secondClass).doReturn(true);
assertThat(MyClass.isInProgres(), equalTo(true));
```

Но если бы secondClass передовался в конструктор, то я бы мог переопределить поведение метода обьекта, который я передаю.

А так в тестах создал обьект MyClass и он инжектит не понятно что и не проверить тестами работу.

Comment: Есть вариант рефлексией сделать это. С другой стороны, можно сделать в классе инъекцию именно конструктора. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381846/why-use-constructor-over-setter-injection-in-cdi/19382081#19382081) сравнивается инъекция конструктора с инъекцией переменной.

Comment: Не могу в конструкторе. Циркулярная зависимость появляется, так устроен код(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325403/how-to-mock-an-inject-interface/35325581#35325581

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Лучше всего избавится от этой привычки делать инъекцию приватным полям. Лучший способ это впихнуть инъекцию через конструктор, тогда у вас не будет никаких проблем в тестах:

   ```
   @Inject
   public MyClass(SecondClass secondClass) { *** }
   ```
2. Вариация прошлого - через сеттер. Но это если не стремитесь к иммутабельности:

   ```
   @Inject
   public void setSecondClass(SecondClass secondClass) { *** }
   ```
3. Чуть большее зло - это тестирование с использованием SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. Тогда мы объявляем контекст:

   ```
   @Configuration
   class TestContext {
       @Bean
       public void SecondClass secondClassProvider() { Mockito.mock(... }
   }

   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestContext.class)
   public class Test {
       @Inject
       MyClass myClass;
   }
   ```
4. Самое большое зло - это рефлексия:

   ```
   ReflectionTestUtils.setField("secondClass", ...)
   ```

Comment: У меня в классе MyClass заинжектен SecondClass в приватной переменной. И наоборот, в SecondClass заинжектен MyClass. Если я в обеих классах засуну в конструктор, нолучу ошибку(

Comment: Тогда сеттеры - ваш вариант. Если вы со спокйной душой допустили цикличискую зависимость, сомневаюсь что у вас будет болеть душа от излишней мутабельности ))

Comment: @ks_on_v Используй `@Lazy` в одном из конструкторов

Comment: А хотя я ещё забыл один вариант. Спринг не требует, чтобы конструктор по умолчанию был public. Вы можете оставить все как есть у вас и добивать два конструктора, с параметром SecondClass и приватный без параметров. А Lazy как вам выше написали может не прокатить при циклической зависимости. Хотя можно проверить.

Comment: @NickSavenia Спасибо!!! Помогло. Ну и грязь))))

Comment: Из доки по @Lazy "In addition to its role for component initialization, this annotation may also be placed on injection points marked with Autowired or Inject: In that context, it leads to the creation of a lazy-resolution proxy for all affected dependencies, as an alternative to using ObjectFactory or Provider.". Не знаю хорошо это или плохо, думаю в большинстве случаев безвредно. Но имейте ввиду, что в этом случае будет создан прокси, что накладывает некоторый overhead на создание прокси и собственно проксирование вызовов.

Comment: А как тестить-то, когда классы друг у друга в конструкторах через @Lazy?)))

Comment: Вы тогда можете создать класс без помощи спринга, просто через конструктор.

Comment: @Uraty SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass(????); MyClass myClass = new MyClass(secondClass); А как тогда SecondClass  создать, он тоже в констркуторе MyClass использует....

Comment: Так а Mockito вам зачем? )